# How to download all images from a forum thread with wget

Tags: wget

For example in a thread that is 30 pages long and the url ends in page=XX is there a way to make a loop that would increment the page each time and download the images only

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sitax:

`wget -r -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://www.domain.com`.

If you want to download all the pics in one folder use this:

`wget -r -P /save/location -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://www.domain.co`

-r enables recursive retrieval.

-P sets the directory prefix where all files and directories are saved to.

-A sets a whitelist for retrieving only certain file types. Strings and patterns are accepted, and both can be used in a comma separated list (as seen above). See Types of Files for more information

Comment: On this thread for example http://67-72chevytrucks.com/vboard/showthread.php?t=513377&page=10 thats not going to work is it?

Comment: Yes it will work. Try.